# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error for setDeviceCredentialAllowed()

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I am trying to create an authentication system for my App.
When I compile the code, Android Studio throws the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setDeviceCredentialAllowed(Z)Landroid/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt$Builder; in class Landroid/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt$Builder' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

I followed some other possible solutions such as `Invalidating Caches and Restarting my Android Studio` but it didn't solve the issue

I am using 
    `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03`

```
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplication().getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if(keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Using keyguard",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Builder biometricPromptBuilder = new Builder(this);

                biometricPromptBuilder.setTitle("Title");
                biometricPromptBuilder.setSubtitle("Subtitle");
                biometricPromptBuilder.setDescription("Discription");
                biometricPromptBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", newExecutor, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
                biometricPromptBuilder.setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true);
                android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = biometricPromptBuilder.build();
                CancellationSignal cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
                biometricPrompt.authenticate(cancellationSignal, newExecutor, new android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString) {
                        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode, CharSequence helpString) {
                        super.onAuthenticationHelp(helpCode, helpString);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The expected output should be a successful compilation of the App

Comment: *I am using androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03 ... `android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPromp` .... `android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricPrompt`* **no, you are not**

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? The stable release of the library is out: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric

Comment: Also this blog post may be able to help: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html

Answer (score 0):

The `androidx` API was [released](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric) in `beta01`, while the framework `(android.hardware.biometrics)` API was released in `29`.

Edit: Just re-read your post, you are using the framework's version of the API. What is your target API level? The framework's version is only available `29+`. You should consider using the `androidx.biometric` version of the API.